How do I apply a post process animation blueprint to a skeleton?
I tried to migrate the rifle anims from the lyra sample project. I am using the same skeleton as the Lyra project, but the wrist is twisted once they are retargeted. If I open the anim before retargeting, I can see a notification in the viewport that says there is a post process anim blueprint running with a button to disable it, and when I do so, It results in the same wrist twisting issue. Cool, it's not an issue with retargeting, it just needs that post process abp. I tried to retargeting the anims with the post process abp and the poses it uses, but when I open an anim there is no notification in the viewport that says the post process ABP is running and the wrist is still twisted, even though it exist and is assigned to the skeleton.
I've scoured the post process abp for anything that might get it to run on my skeleton and can't find anything and the skeleton for anything that might assign the abp to it and can't find anything.

I figured it out. The post process animation blueprint is assigned to the skeletal mesh, not the skeleton. There is an option to assign one under the skeletal mesh dropdown in the asset details of the skeletal mesh.
